# is there any limitation of using over 1000 images in Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

In the mapbox studio I can see a message appearing under my image uploader that I am over the limit which I did not find elsewhere in docs mentioned.

Is it just a message reminding people to not put too many data icons there or it might cause any issues that some (e.g. oldest uploaded) of the icons won't we displayed in web/mobile apps because it won't load over 1000 images?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[Sprites](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#sprites):

> Sprites are managed on a per-style basis. Each sprite belongs to a
> style, so the sprite limit of 1,000 images is also a per-style limit.

Comment: the source is here for completeness (https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#response-retrieve-a-maps-wmts-document) but can it cause any issues or it is just a recommendation? It looks like everything works with my style...